# use the _tracktrans from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-analytics-api

i'm currently reading to the google analytics documentation for ecommerce and I have to ask you a question.
Suppose that my user stops the command. So informations sent to google servers through _addtrans and _addItem and to be cancelled. I have to resend the same informations with a minus sign (ex: with a 17 as price, i've to resend -17 to "mark the command as cancelled".
In my reading, I find a _tracktrans method which seems to send informations only if command is confirmed (than i guess it's a tag you had on a confirmation page)
Than my question is: what's the difference between the two methods ? (cancelling vs adding tag in the success page).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You always need to use _tracktrans() in order to send the data to Google Analytics. If you do not, then your _addtrans does nothing. All it does is create an object that is prepared to be sent to the Google Analytics services. As explained on [the developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEcommerce#-_tracktrans).

The best way to use this is to do the addtrans and tracktrans on your confirmation page, and not before payment. Since users can leave your payment page without going back to the site.

But if a user can cancel an order after payment, then using the -[price] transaction to cancel a transaction in Google Analytics is usefull.